# Changing from Linux Suse 11 to Win 7 x64 failed

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot

I bought a new laptop (HP ProBook 4540s, Intel Pentium B980, 4GB, DDR3 1333 MHz) which came with a Linux SUSE Enterprise. As this laptop is going to be used by a IT beginner, it has to run on Win 7. 
So, for installing Win7, I did as I have done several times on my own laptop - booted from a Win7 DVD and followed the instructions it gave me. But after formatting the disks, the installing looked like it was doing fine until the first restart - then it gave a disk error ("Disk error, Press any key to restart") and when a key is pressed, it starts HP Advanced System Diagnostics, which is... useless.
I alse have tried using an USB for the installing (set the boot priorities accordingly on BIOS) but it just gave the same error.

So, if there is anyone who can help me based on this ambiguous description, I would be forever grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from the DVD again and try the following:
2. Boot from the Windows 7 DVD
3. Click Install Now & Accept License Agreement
4. When the option is displayed to select an installation type, click `(Custom Advanced)`
5. Click Drive Options
6. Select the drives click `Delete`
7. Click `New`
8. Click Apply
9. Click OK
10. Click `Format` and click `Next` to proceed with the installation

try this & feedback here.

Comment: There is a drive called HP_Tools, is it necessary to delete that too?

Comment: I don't have HP But try without delete it, if Problem still exist, Try to deleted.

Comment: yeah, the problem still stays. Now, when the installation goes on the restart, it says: "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD.... Disk error. Press any key to restart".

Comment: Now Try to delete that Partition! But if you can, backup it.

Comment: Nope, no difference

Comment: Did you delete **all** of old partitions and create new partitions again ?

Comment: I deleted the ones that could be deleted. The first one, which is 20 GB could only be formatted

Comment: I think you have to delete all of partitions, Next create them again. If you can't do it with Windows LIVE CD try Linux LIVE CD.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at at your partition table. You may have Windows arranged on a partition that the boot loader does not like, or possible MBR problems.

There are several LiveCD utilities with partition editors that will help you approach this. The partition editor in the Windows installer is really not a powerful tool, and hides much of the useful information.  As for a trustworthy tool, you might just want to grab an Ubuntu Live CD (64bit) and once running, fire up `gparted`, a partition table editor.

Posting information about your partition table will help rule out any problems there. Try removing all partitions if in doubt (remember to flush the changes before rebooting).  and then run the Windows DVD. Let the Windows installer set up the raw disk how it wants, and then maybe leave some room to put linux back on when Windows is finished.

Did you try to install Windows next to SuSe, or did you wipe the whole disk as per the Windows Installer?